# jquery form field message on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

http://jsfiddle.net/XeELs/24/

I'm having problems with this Fiddle is not working the message Error. I'm using the CSS3-html5 form validation and I need to implement it within CSS possibly  `valid` and `invalid`

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? When I tried your fiddle error messages popped up next to the fields.

Comment: What is you question ? what are you actually trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

There a a few things wrong with your code ....

- Its not valid ... your missing closing brakets
- You are using the same variables multiple times - `$field` and `$message`
- You use var `$field = $('input[type=email]').attr('id');` and then later in the code you user `$('#' + $field + ')` where `$('input[type=email]')` gives you exactly what you need !
- `id`s should be unique - you are using the same `id` in multiple places for example `id="email"`

here

```
<div id="email" class="outerDiv">
    <label for="email">Email</label> 
    <input  name="email" type="email" id="email" class="placeholder" required />
    <span class="input-validation"></span>
</div>
```

What are you actually trying to achieve ????

Comment: I want to validate the fields and proceed adding a class or something.

Comment: @DD77 How are you going to validate the fields ? (may i suggest a jquery plugin for validation -> http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Comment: @DD77 ok ... how are you going to validate ? take the email field for example - what validation do you want to perform ? and if the validation fails what do you want to happen ?

Comment: @DD77 and my first question - which you have missed twice ! how are you going to validate ? empty ? matches a pattern ? doesnt contain ? contains ?